# Does Fortigate 100A support IPv6?

Tags: firewall, ipv6, fortigate

Tried searching through the net but couldn't find any info since the product is already discontinued. Can anyone confirm if this particular product supports IPv6?

Comment: You mean the little firewall appliance that came out some 10 years ago? Not likely.

Comment: I thought so too. I just need some assurance on this. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

The question should be: "Does the 100A support a FortiOS version that supports IPv6?"

That answer is **yes**.

Although [the 100A is EOL](http://www.firewalls.com.au/docs/EOL_FG100A.pdf) (as of April 2009), and you should not expect support on it passed April 2014, a FortiOS version with support for the 100A and IPv6, [FortiOS v4.0 MR3 Patch 15](ftp://support.fortinet.com/FortiGate/v4.00/4.0MR3/MR3_Patch_15/) (the latest and arguably last V4 FortiOS available), does exist and can be found [on the Fortinet FTP](ftp://support.fortinet.com/FortiGate/v4.00/4.0MR3/MR3_Patch_15/).

[All documentation that applies to](http://docs.fortinet.com/fgt40mr3.html) and all features that are included in this FortiOS version will apply... to this FortiOS version.

Conjecture: Due to the product being EOL, you should really move away if you are using this to protect essential infrastructure that needs a high level of security; but if you're messing around and are using at home, I would suppose it should not be a problem.  [Fortinet allows for a credit towards an upgrade if you turn in your old hardware](http://www.fortinet.com/promo/2013-trade-up.html), or they may just allow you to keep it (as they did mine).